# Creating new matrix from complex + real eigenvectors. Splitting complex conjugates into real columns using real and complex values respectively

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I am looking to separate any complex eigenvectors/values from a matrix into real and imaginary components sorted into a new matrix of all real values where the real part of any complex conjugate pairs is in its own column, and the imaginary part is now a real part in its own column... It's probably easier to show with an example, if my 3x3 matrix gives me these eigenvectors:

```
         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]
[1,] 0.3-0.4i 0.3+0.4i -0.6+0i
[2,] 0.3+0.1i 0.3-0.1i -0.8+0i
[3,] 0.8+0.0i 0.8+0.0i  0.1+0i
```

I would like my code to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]
[1,]    0.3      0.4      -0.6
[2,]    0.3      0.1      -0.8
[3,]    0.8      0.0       0.1
```

I don't think I care if that zero in [3,2] is NA or 0.

I'm a total beginner at coding in R. I tried to do it iteratively which is maybe the wrong approach to begin with, and looking at my attempt its obvious now why it doesn't work but I wanted to include it to show you what you're working with. Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```r
dispersal_matrix = matrix(c( 1,-2,-3,
                            -1, 1, 3,
                             2, 1, 3), nrow=3)

d = 3  #in the end the user needs to be able to choose how many eigenvectors they want
right_eigs = eigen(dispersal_matrix) 
n = nrow(dispersal_matrix) 

all_eigenvectors = right_eigs$vectors
real_split_eigenvectors = matrix(nrow = n, ncol = d) 

is_conj = FALSE

for(j in 1:d){
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(abs(Im(all_eigenvectors[i,j]))>1e-8){
      real_split_eigenvectors[i,j] = Re(all_eigenvectors[i,j])
      real_split_eigenvectors[i,j+1] = Im(all_eigenvectors[i,j])
      is_conj = TRUE
    }
    else{
      real_split_eigenvectors[i,j] = Re(all_eigenvectors[i,j])
    }
  }
  if(is_conj == TRUE) {
    j+1
    is_conj = FALSE
  }
}
```

The example up top is rounded for easier reading.

Comment: is it true that the first 2 eigenvectors will be conjugate of each other?

Comment: Not necessarily the first 2, but all complex eigenvectors have a conjugate!

Answer (score 0):

```
  is_conj = FALSE

  for(j in 1:d){ # << PHI >> RIGHT eigenvectors real matrix
    if(any(abs(Im(Phi_complex[,j]))<1e-8)){
      Phi_real[,j] = Re(Phi_complex[,j])
    } else if(is_conj ){
      Phi_real[,j] = Im(Phi_complex[,j])
      is_conj = FALSE # switches the state of the conjugate variable to false so the next round of the loop will go to the next step in the if-else chain
    }else {
      Phi_real[,j] = Re(Phi_complex[,j])
      is_conj = TRUE # returns the conjugate state back to TRUE for the loop
    }
  }
```

My solution with help from a friend